# knockout.js two-way binding of checkboxes with observableArrays

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout, and I'm having some trouble getting the checkbox to do what I want. First of all, here's the fiddle for what I've tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/imagitron/mMc6k/, and the offending lines of code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedItems"/>
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is link two arrays via the checkbox, so that when I click the checkbox, it stores the object from the definition array and saves it to the selectedItems array. Also the removeItems function isn't clearing the array when I press the button.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: one observation - `definition` is an array of objects so you'd want to use a for loop `for(var i = 0; i < definition.length; i++) {}` to loop through the objects in the array on line 19.

Comment: Always include **all** relevant markup and code **in** the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: When you edited your question you completely changed its meaning. This is not really the idea of the edit feature. When a future reader sees the answers and comments they will not make any sense at all anymore. If your original question was answered, please accept the answer and leave the question as is (that now means, please undo your edit). If you have a new question, please create a new post.

Comment: In particular, the JS code you posted is not found in the jsfiddle that you reference, while your answer to T.J. Crowder sounds as if it was - very confusing.

Comment: Ah, well now I feel retarded. Thanks, I'll revert the question back.

Comment: Well done, thanks! Don't hesitate to post your other issue as a new question if you're still struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported out of the box by knockout. The `checked` binding binds the state of a single checkbox to a single boolean property. However for this to work in two ways, you need to indicate the function name instead of a function call (`$root.someProperty` instead of `$root.someProperty()`).

The `value` binding does not make sense for checkboxes. It is used to bind the value of other input fields such as text boxes.

To achieve what you want you could define an array with an object for each checkbox like so:

```
var items = ko.mapping.fromJS([
    { label: 'Foo', checked: false },
    { label: 'Bar', checked: false }
]);
```

And bind to it like so:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->

    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked"/>
    <span data-bind="text: label"/>

<!-- /ko -->
```

Then retrieve the checked values of the array using a `ko.computed` function:

```
var checkedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return _.filter(items, function (item) { return item.checked() });
});
```

*(this is a hidden ad for the underscore library - if you don't have it, knockout has a similar function as far as I can remember)*

Comment: Thanks, adding the checked value to my array objects helped me get on the right track.